# Class property changing

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I have a designed a Class which acts as if it is a CD, I have also another Class which tests the Class I have designed.
The test class makes a new object of CD and fills it with variables etc..

My problem is that the testing Class says my Class fails due to a variable array changing after the object has been made and these variables aren't directly changing the actual Class properties, how do I stop this?

Test Class:

```
string[] myCdTracks = { "Song 1", "Song 2", "Song 3" };
string[] myCdTracks2 = { "Song 1", "Song 2", "Song 3" };

CD myCd = new CD("My Songs", "Fergus", "Rock", myCdTracks);
for (int i = 0; i < myCdTracks.Length; i++)    
    {
```

It changes its value here when it shouldn't be.

```
        myCdTracks[i] = "aaaa";
    }
    result = "PASS";
    if (myCd.Tracks.Length != testArray.Length)
    {
        result = "FAIL";
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < myCd.Tracks.Length; i++)
        {
            if (myCd.Tracks[i] != testArray[i])
            {
                result = "FAIL";
            }
        }
    }
```

My CD Class:

```
public class CD
{
    string _Name;
    string _Artist;
    string _Genre;
    string[] _Tracks;

    public CD(string name, string artist, string genre, string[] tracks)
    {
        _Name = name;
        _Artist = artist;
        _Genre = genre;
        _Tracks = tracks;
    }

    // ... Some properties

    public string[] Tracks
    {
        get
        {
            return _Tracks;
        }
        set
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _Tracks.Length; i++)
            {
                _Tracks[i]= value[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you even trying to accomplish here? Because I can tell you right now there is probably a far better way of doing it than the hot mess of using a property setter to not actually set a property.

Comment: @Brad_Stone, also note your setter on Tracks is prone to explode. You loop over the input array without regard to its length or even its existence.

Comment: This is only a practice exercise in understanding simple get and set, nothing advance and this was only so I can quickly get an understanding of why Tracks would get over-written.
Set as an simple trivial task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My problem is that the testing Class says my Class fails due to a variable array changing after the object has been made and these variables aren't directly changing the actual Class properties, how do I stop this?

The problem is that you've just copied the *reference* to the array of track names in the constructor. That means any changes to the array from the outside will still be visible via your reference. One simple option is to clone the array:

```
_Tracks = (String[]) tracks.Clone();
```

... or even change the variable type and create a read-only collection:

```
_Tracks = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(tracks);
```

Fortunately you don't need to worry about the contents of the string objects themselves changing, as strings are immutable. It *is* important that you understand what's going on with your program in its current form though - and my [article on reference types vs value types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html) may help.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the help.
I will accept your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Thanks for the more info.
Yeah I do understand the concept of why it was changing and how I was not making a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Also note, that in your property setter for the `Tracks` property, you'll most likely run into troubles if the array to be set has more elements than the current `_Tracks` array.

I suggest to use Jon Skeet's variant in both the constructor *and* the property setter.